# How does a compiler/assembler make sense of processor core registers?

Tags: arm, microcontroller, cpu-registers, cortex-m

My question is specific to arm cortex M3 micro-controllers. Every peripheral on the micro controller is memory mapped and those memory addresses are used in processing.

For Eg.,: GPIOA->ODR = 0;
This will write a 0 at address 0x4001080C.
This address is defined in the device specific file of the micro controller.

Now, the cortex M3 has processor core registers R0-R12 (general purpose). I want to know, do these registers also have some address like other peripherals?

So, if I have instruction: MOV R0, #10;
will R0 be translated to some address when assembled? Do core registers have special numeric addresses exclusive for core peripherals. Is address of R0 defined in any file (I couldn't find any) like that of GPIOA? Or is it that register R0 and other core registers are referred to as R0 and their respective names only so that the assembler sees "R0" and generates the opcode from it?

I have this confusion because some 8 bit controllers also have addresses for general purpose registers.

Thanks,
Navin

Comment: No, they're registers. They live inside the CPU.

Comment: Some processor architectures map their registers into the general address space, but AFAIK ARM is not one of them. Of course the register number will need to be encoded in the instruction that uses the register, so you could consider it a special (very small) address space distinct from memory address space.

Comment: Correct ARM is not one of them.  Also note that for the GPIO, UART, etc registers the processor has absolutely no clue what is out there, the programmer directly or indirectly knows that these addresses mean something and instructs the processor to read/write them.  The general purpose cpu registers r0-r15 are only accessible to us through instructions.

Comment: As mentioned the instruction itself has three or four bits depending on the instruction that determine which register(s) is(are) being used by the instruction.  Due to register banking if any, those bits plus others will likely address into a "register file" a very small sram which is the flip flops/memory that actually hold the general purpose registers, we cannot access that sram directly, and not guaranteed they use a register file, but it is common for various reasons to implement something like this in that way in a design.

Comment: as programmers our view of the world is there are instructions with some bits that define which GPR we want to use, and that is all the access we have.  There are some processors where the GPR's are addressable in memory space, but most, not.

Comment: you are not the first one to be confused this has been asked and answered here at SO at least once if not more.

Answer (score 1):

Registers like `R0`-`R12` or `SP`, `PC`, .. are registers inside CPU core and they are not mapped to global address space. Access to these registers is possible only from assembler.

And also direct access to core registers from higher level languages like C is not possible, because they are not addressable. These registers are used for internal processing and they are transparent for the programmer.

But registers like GPIOA->ODR are mapped to global address space, so each register has own address.

Answer (score 0):

General Purpose registers are meant to do general purpose operations with the CPU. This is just like we use few temporary variables in any programming language. So if we relate this to your question, CPU requires few reserved memory segments to do it's basic operations. Hence there is no point in sharing this to outside world. This is how ARM based processors work.

Answer (score 0):

You happened to have picked an instruction that is really easy to see...

```
.thumb

mov r0,#10
mov r1,#10
mov r2,#10
mov r3,#10
mov r4,#10
mov r5,#10
mov r6,#10
mov r7,#10
```

assemble then disassemble to see the machine code

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   200a        movs    r0, #10
   2:   210a        movs    r1, #10
   4:   220a        movs    r2, #10
   6:   230a        movs    r3, #10
   8:   240a        movs    r4, #10
   a:   250a        movs    r5, #10
   c:   260a        movs    r6, #10
   e:   270a        movs    r7, #10
```

there will be three or four bits depending on the instruction and instruction set (arm vs thumb (and then thumb2 extensions)) that specify the register.  In this case those bits happen to line up nicely with the hex representation of the machine code instruction so we can see the 0 through 7.  For a cortex-m3 many of the thumb instructions are limited to r0-r7 (implying a 3 bit field within the instruction) with one or two to move between the lower and upper, thumb2 extensions allow for more access to the full r0-r15 (and thus will have a 4 bit field in the instruction).  You should get the armv7m architectural reference manual which is what is associated with the cortex-m3 (after you get the cortex-m3 technical reference manual and see that it uses the armv7m architecture), you can also get the oldest armv5 architectural reference manual as it has the oldest description of the thumb instruction set which is the one instruciton set that is compatible across all arm cores armv6m covers the cortex-m0 which has a lot fewer thumb2 extensions then armv7m which covers the cortex-m3 m4 and m7 have tons more thumb2 extensions.

another example that takes only a second to try

```
.thumb

mov r0,r0
mov r1,r1
mov r2,r2
mov r3,r3
mov r4,r4
mov r5,r5
mov r6,r6
mov r7,r7

mov r0,r0
mov r1,r0
mov r2,r0
mov r3,r0
mov r4,r0
mov r5,r0
mov r6,r0
mov r7,r0

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   1c00        adds    r0, r0, #0
   2:   1c09        adds    r1, r1, #0
   4:   1c12        adds    r2, r2, #0
   6:   1c1b        adds    r3, r3, #0
   8:   1c24        adds    r4, r4, #0
   a:   1c2d        adds    r5, r5, #0
   c:   1c36        adds    r6, r6, #0
   e:   1c3f        adds    r7, r7, #0
  10:   1c00        adds    r0, r0, #0
  12:   1c01        adds    r1, r0, #0
  14:   1c02        adds    r2, r0, #0
  16:   1c03        adds    r3, r0, #0
  18:   1c04        adds    r4, r0, #0
  1a:   1c05        adds    r5, r0, #0
  1c:   1c06        adds    r6, r0, #0
  1e:   1c07        adds    r7, r0, #0
```

note that the bits didnt line up as nicely as before with hex values, doesnt matter look at the binary to see the three bits changing from instruction to instruction.

in this case the assembler chose to use an add instead of mov

> Notes:
>
> Encoding: This instruction is encoded as ADD Rd, Rn, #0.

and

> Notes
>
> Operand restriction: If a low register is specified for  and 
>   H1==0 and H2==0), the result is UNPREDICTABLE .

All this plus a zillion more things you learn when you read the documentation.  http://infocenter.arm.com. on the left arm architecture then reference manuals you may have to sacrifice an email address.  you can google arm architectural reference manual and you may get lucky...